# Finding out the closer time between two times

Tags: java, android

I wish to ask some question at Java. I have list of time (String) which i parsed from JSON data. I need to find which time is closer to system time. Its like this, now time is 16:40. And my time list contains 
"16:32", "16:38", "16:44", "16:50" and so on. For 16:40, 16:38 is closer than 16:44 and i need to find this. I've tried to get current index and next index, parse them and initate new Calender and so on.  But i cant figure out how can i do next.

Any solutions for this problem?

```
       String returnTime = current.getDonus();
        if (i < list.size() + 1) {
            TimeList nextOne=list.get(i+1);
            String nextReturnTime = nextOne.getDonus();
            String[] parsedNextReturn = nextReturnTime.split(":");
            String[] parsedReturn = returnTime.split(":");

            Date date = new Date();

            Calendar calNextReturn= Calendar.getInstance();
            calNextReturn.setTime(date);
            calNextReturn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parsedNextReturn[0]));
            calNextReturn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parsedNextReturn[1]));
            calNextReturn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calNextReturn.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Calendar calCurrentReturn= Calendar.getInstance();
            calCurrentReturn.setTime(date);
            calCurrentReturn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parsedReturn[0]));
            calCurrentReturn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parsedReturn[1]));
            calCurrentReturn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calCurrentReturn.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Calendar calSystem = Calendar.getInstance();
            calSystem.setTime(date);
            calSystem.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSystem.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        }
```

Comment: find minimum of `abs(givenTime.getTimeInMillis() - timeToCompare.getTimeInMillis())`

Comment: But for Math.Abs, i need two parameter. I have 3.

Comment: huh? mat.abs has 1 parameter ...it simply `(i)-> i > 0 ? i : -i;` `givenTime` is your system time and `timeToCompare` is one of the time from the json ... now you need to iterate and find minimum

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        long smallestABS = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeClosest;
        for (long time : timeList) {
            long abs = Math.abs(systemTime - time);
            if(smallestABS > abs){
                smallestABS = abs;                
                timeClosest = time;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm using abs, thats ok. But now it seems it gets time as AM/PM instead of 24h.

Comment: It is not important whether it is am/pm, you should format your time to milliseconds. You can use the calendar to do it, set there your full date and use calendar.getTimeInMillis() then u can compare it to systemTime